# Quantile Curves Without Crossing in Mathematica

Tags: fitting

I was looking at this article by Antonov:
https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/quantile-regression-through-linear-programming/

and I was wondering if anyone has developed any package or code for Mathematica to deal with **quantiles curve crossing**, a well known problem with quantile regression.

To make my question more clear, here below is an example from the He's paper "Quantile Curves Without Crossing" (1997): the image on the left shows the result of RQ (Regression Quantiles) with crossing curves vs. the RRQ (Restricted Regression Quantiles) output on the right hand side of the image, where the curves are NOT crossing.

I am trying to achieve an output like the one on the right side of the image, i.e. non-crossing curves and I wondering how to do that in Mathematica.

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you started with a representative example.

Comment: My dataset is simply a x,y non-normally distributed, like this:

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R65ug.png

Comment: I meant actual data and code.

Comment: My question is more high level at the moment: are there any publicly available Mathematica packages that deal with constrained quantile regression to avoid curves crossing? I have no code at the moment, I am just trying to understand if Mathematica can do this, or if I have to write a new code ad hoc, from scratch. To say it in other words: I am just trying to assess how difficult it will be to do this in Mathematica, knowing that it is possible to do it in R with relatively little difficulty. I hope my question makes more sense now.

Comment: High level or not you should follow @Feyre 's advice.  You'll get more interest if you provide actual code and data.  That shows that you, too, have an invested interest.  In the meantime you can use `RLink` to call *R* from *Mathematica*.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, I think I am probably going to figure out how to do this in R.

Comment: (As far as I know) in general, the problem with crossing regression quantiles is considered non-solvable.